# PHP: preg_replace problem with bracket interaction ')'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

im trying to replicate blade from laravel in order to learn but i have encountered a problem

when using preg_replace to create the parser everything goes well except for a certain interaction with a bracket; ')'

ThisIsGonnaBeParsed.php

```
@if ($user->loggedIn() || true)

    <p>welcome {{$user->name}}</p>

@endif

@if (true)

    <p>hello</p>

@endif
```

PATTERN => REPLACE

```
        '/{{(.+?)}}/s'              => '<?php echo \1; ?>',
        '/@if(\s|)\((.+?)\)/s'      => '<?php if (\2): ?>',
        '/@endif/'                  => '<?php endif; ?>'
```

as you can see, everything is replaced except for the stuff stored between the brackets. but something goes wrong in the results.

FULL RESULT

```
<?php if ($user->loggedIn(): ?> || true)

    <p>welcome <?php echo $user->name; ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (true): ?>

    <p>hello</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

THE PART WITH THE ERROR

```
<?php if ($user->loggedIn(): ?> || true)
```

as you can see, as soon as it encountered the ) it threw everything from that point on at the back of the string

THE RESULT I ACTUALLY WANTED

```
<?php if ($user->loggedIn() || true): ?>
```

i have tried googling but i couldnt find any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your inside parentheses match `.+?` is not greedy, so it stops at the first `)` which is the one at the end of `$user->loggedIn()`. You can resolve that by using a greedy match, but you also need to remove the `s` modifier which allows `.` to match newline as that will otherwise cause it to match up to the `)` at the end of `if (true)`. That will mean your `if` conditions cannot go over a line break, but if that is ok, then this should work:

```
$replacements = array(
        '/{{(.+?)}}/'              => '<?php echo $1; ?>',
        '/@if\s*\((.+)\)/'         => '<?php if ($1): ?>',
        '/@endif/'                 => '<?php endif; ?>'
    );

echo preg_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $code);
```

Output:

```
<?php if ($user->loggedIn() || true): ?>

    <p>welcome <?php echo $user->name; ?></p>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if (true): ?> 

    <p>hello</p> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/v254b)

Comment: DUDE, damn, thx man. this problem was keeping me awake for many nights and days. THANKS